# Regex Pattern string

Tags: c#, regex

I have text following by a numeric prefix , I want to split them using Regex
I noticed that the text part start after a prefix like this:

010802026002000300.00000000026.00

010801007002000050.00000000000.00

030801007002000020.00000000049.50

I'm straggling to construct a pattern string in order to recognise the above prefix.

Can anyone help me on this one ?

```
var readText = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);            
List<string> ReadLines = readText.ToList();
string input = null;
foreach(string str in ReadLines) {input += str;}

string pattern = ""; // Can't figure what to set here???

string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Comment: What is the desired `result`, please?

Comment: `var result = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.UTF8).Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"^\d{18}\.\d{11}\.\d{2}", "")).ToArray();` - if the lines start with that pattern and you want to remove that part.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay You really should delimit the periods so that it's an exact match instead of "match any character"

Comment: Unrelated: `ReadLines` already gives you an `IEnumarable<string>`. Why make it a List and then concat them? Just use [`ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_)

Comment: Why use Regex on something so simple.  Just use String Split method.

Comment: The approach @WiktorStribiżew provides is functionally quite different from OP's `foreach(string str in File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.UTF8)) {input += str;}` particularly with respect to line endings.

Comment: Am I right in that you have text like  `010802026002000300.00000000026.00AAA010801007002000050.00000000000.00BBB030801007002000020.00000000049.50CCC` and you want { `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC` }?  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the confusion, I posted only a draft , this is what I wanted:

```
string path = FilePath.Text.ToString();
            string pattern = @"^\d{18}\.\d{11}\.\d{2}";
            string input = null;

            List<string> ReadLines = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.UTF8).ToList();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Text");
            dt.Columns.Add("Pattern");

            foreach(string line in ReadLines)
            {
                input += line;
                Match m = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Pattern"] = m.Value;
                    dr["Text"] = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    input = null;
                }
```

}